# If specific checkbox is selected, to make text box compulsory (checkbox group)

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have a group of check boxes with the same name. The user needs to select at least one checkbox and if "Others" is selected, the "Promotion_Others" text box is compulsory.

I am not sure how to do this with the check boxes all having the same name.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Prefer_Promotion[]" value="food_and_beverages_discounts" >Food & beverages discounts</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="Prefer_Promotion[]" value="complimentary_hotel_facilities">Complimentary hotel facilities</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="Prefer_Promotion[]" value="complimentary_gym_access">Complimentary gym access</label>
<input  type="checkbox" name="Prefer_Promotion[]" value="others">Others</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="Promotion_Others" value="" maxlength="50"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#mysubmit').click(function () {
                    if ($('input[type=checkbox]').is(':checked')) {
                        // atleast one checkbox checked, do something...
                        // now check seleted is othere

                        $('input[type=checkbox]input:checkbox:checked').each(function () {
                            var value = $(this).attr('value');
                            if ('others' === value) {

                                var others_value = $('.form-control').val();
                                if (!others_value) {
                                    alert('Please fill text field');
                                    return false;
                                } else
                                    return true;
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });

            });

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="myform">
            <input type="checkbox" name="Prefer_Promotion[]" value="food_and_beverages_discounts" >Food & beverages discounts</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="Prefer_Promotion[]" value="complimentary_hotel_facilities">Complimentary hotel facilities</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="Prefer_Promotion[]" value="complimentary_gym_access">Complimentary gym access</label>
            <input  type="checkbox" name="Prefer_Promotion[]" value="others">Others</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Promotion_Others" value="" maxlength="50"/>
            <input type="button" value="submit" id="mysubmit"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Try this snippet. Comment if help needed

Comment: I am thinking of using jQuery Required validation but i am having difficulty with the second part of the If statement.                                                                              Promotion_Others: {
   required:{       
      depends: function(element) {
          if (($("input[name='Prefer_Promotion[]']:checked").length > 0) && (if checkbox array contains 'others')){
  return true;
  }
      }
   }
},

Comment: @user558085 That is a completely different question. Please accept a correct answer to this question and then ask that as a new question. As soon as you post the new question you will instantly get dozens of eyes reading it and trying to help, instead of waiting on the few people now following this question to  respond.

Comment: I tested this code. and it works. @user558085 : You can accept the answer if this helped